# Extract strongly-typed data context instance from arbitrary query

Tags: entity-framework, entity-framework-6

**Background**

We have a class library which has a grid (inherits from WPF DataGrid) with refresh functionality. The grid has a `IQueryable Query` property, which enables the refresh. Each grid's query is defined not in the class library, but in the referencing end-project:

```
var dg = new RefreshableDataGrid();
dg.Query = () => new ProjectDbContext().Persons;
```

Each grid also has a textbox for text filtering. When text is entered in the filter, an expression is generated which checks if any string property or string-convertible property (using `SqlFunctions.StringConvert`) contains the filter string. The expression is then appended to the original query as an argument to `Where`, and thus only the records containing matching strings are returned.

```
//within the class library
//pseudo-code -- this is actually done via reflection, because at compile time the
//actual type of the grid is not known, and there is no generic placeholder
this.ItemsSource = this.Query.Where(filterExpression)
```

In some cases, the filter logic is defined in end-projects, on the entity type. For example:

```
public interface IFilterable {
    public Expression<Func<String, Boolean>> TextSearchExpression();
}

public class Email {
    public int ID {get;set;}
    public int PersonID {get;set;}
    public string Address {get;set;}
}

public class Person : IFilterable
    public int ID {get;set;}
    public string LastName {get;set;}
    public string FirstName {get;set;}
    public Expression<Func<String, Boolean>> TextSearchExpression() {
        Dim ctx = new ProjectDbContext();
        return phrase => LastName.Contains(phrase) || FirstName.Contains(phrase) || 
            ctx.Emails.Where(x => x.PersonID = ID && x.Address.Contains(prase).Any();
    }
}
```

This expression tree uses an instance of the project-specific context, which is a different instance from that of the original query. Queries cannot use components from multiple contexts (at least not in Entity Framework). I can rewrite the expression tree to use a specific instance, but I need to extract the original instance from the query.

It seems obvious that the query holds some reference to the context instance, otherwise the query would not be able to return results.

I do not want to pass the context instance to the class library.

Hence:

**Given a query, how can I get the strongly-typed `DbContext` instance used to create the query?**

In other words, what goes in the body of this method:

```
DbContext GetDbContext<TSource>(IQueryable<TSource> qry) {
    // ???
}
```

Comment: "I need the context in order to apply other filters to the original query". No, you don't.

Comment: @haim770 _"No, you don't."_ Yes I do. The project-level filters are defined as expressions, and might make use of additional queries of other instances of the DbContext. I am rewriting the expression so all nodes which inherit from DbContext will instead refer to the original query's context; but in order to do that I need the original query's context.

Comment: This question could use some sample code. To me it's not clear which assembly is referenced by the other. Also, do they both have a reference to some common assembly containing the entity types? If not, this is going to be very awkward.

Comment: What's the point of having reusable filters that depend on the datacontext anyway and then trying to abstract away that same datacontext? I'd say you're making it way too complex...

Comment: @GertArnold See my update. The entity types are defined in an end-project, of which the class library has no compile-time knowledge. And yes, it is quite awkward (reflection, expression trees, reflection and expression trees) but the benefits of abstracting away the filtering logic far outweigh the awkwardness.

Comment: @jeroenh Updated. I thought I was making it simpler. :)

Comment: Looking at the use case, I'm wondering why don't you base your custom filters simply on navigation properties, e.g. instead of `ctx.Emails.Where(x => x.PersonID = ID)` have `public ICollection<Email> Emails { get; set; }`  and use `Emails.Where(x => x.Address.Contains(prase)).Any()`. If you are able to replace `this` with parameter for `LastName` and `FirstName`, the same should work for navigation properties as well (being simple or collection). The point is, if you have a navigation path from any entity to any related entity, then you don't really need the db context.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> It seems obvious that the query holds some reference to the context instance, otherwise the query would not be able to return results.

That's true, but it's implementation specific detail and in EF is encapsulated inside internal members/classes/interfaces.

Also taking into account that `DbContext` is build on top of the `ObjectContext`, holding a reference to the `DbContext` is not strongly necessary. Fortunately that's not the case :)

The following uses reflection and implementation details of the latest EF6.1.3 (tested and working if you don't use some 3rd party extensions like [LinqKit](http://www.albahari.com/nutshell/linqkit.aspx) and similar that replace the query provider):

```
public static DbContext GetDbContext<TSource>(this IQueryable<TSource> query)
{
    const BindingFlags flags = BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.NonPublic | BindingFlags.Public;
    var provider = query.Provider;
    var internalContextProperty = provider.GetType().GetProperty("InternalContext", flags);
    if (internalContextProperty == null) return null;
    var internalContext = internalContextProperty.GetValue(provider, null);
    if (internalContext == null) return null;
    var ownerProperty = internalContext.GetType().GetProperty("Owner", flags);
    if (ownerProperty == null) return null;
    var dbContext = (DbContext)ownerProperty.GetValue(internalContext, null);
    return dbContext;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend passing an instance of MyDataContext into your query function

```
public class DACPerson
{
    public static IQueryable<Person> GetAllAsQueryable(MyDataContext db)
    {
        return db.People.AsQueryable();
    }


}
```

This allows you to do the following in the calling function:

```
public List<Person> UpdateListofPeople(string term)
{
    using(DataContext db = new DataContext())
    {
        var people = DACPerson.GetAllAsQueryable(db);
        var result = people.Where(x=>x.Username.Contains(term)).

        //call other Data Access Component FUnctions here using same DB....
    }
}
```

i.e. you can bring the filtering to the layer above the data access class.

Some people may not like to do this. You may get the advice that its best to keep all entityframeowrk functionality within the same layer and just return the DTO. I like the above approach though. It depends on who will have to maintain each part of your application in the future.

Hope this helps at least

Comment: I explicitly wrote in my question that I didn't want to pass in the context along with the query; the reason being that this complicates the calling API of the datagrid.

Comment: Keep in mind that if the GetAllAsQueryable` is returning a `List<Person>`, that doesn't match the return type of `db.People.AsQueryable()` which is presumably `IQueryable<Person>`.

Comment: As I mentioned in my answer, not everyone wants to use this pattern. I like it because it tends to keep the code in the data layer relatively static, and logical layer can be used to map-filter-query etc. I completely understand if you don't want to pass the content in. As I mentioned at the top, this is just my recommendation

Comment: 1) You know you can edit your answer (click on the **edit** link  under your answer)? 2) Also, I've expanded my question and I'm not sure your answer is at all relevant.

Comment: That is no problem at all. My design philosophy has always been to both minimise the use of reflection which slows down code a lot, and secondly to keep the design manageable, as I stated, the above is just my recommended approach. Good luck with your work and thank you for your feedback.