# How can I sort by primary key or any default value to allow me to Skip and Take in EF on a generic collection?

Tags: c#, reflection, entity-framework-6

I have a method that takes `IQueryable<T>` and I do a bunch of generic stuff on it. Usually the order property will be specified which is fine but sometimes nothing is provided, and I need to order it by something in order to apply skip/take.

I'd be happiest doing this on the primary key, but anything that will work is also good.

I can't seem to get the primary key from the `IQueryable<T>` collection though. I tried some code I found online to loop through `PropertyInfo[] properties = typeof(T).GetProperties();` properties and `GetCustomAttributes()` but there didn't seem to be any attributes at all.

I was using this method but it just gave me `null`:

```
private PropertyInfo GetPrimaryKeyInfo<T>()
{
    PropertyInfo[] properties = typeof(T).GetProperties();
    foreach (PropertyInfo pI in properties)
    {
        System.Object[] attributes = pI.GetCustomAttributes(true);
        foreach (object attribute in attributes)
        {
            if (attribute is EdmScalarPropertyAttribute)
            {
                if ((attribute as EdmScalarPropertyAttribute).EntityKeyProperty == true)
                    return pI;
            }
            else if (attribute is System.Data.Linq.Mapping.ColumnAttribute)
            {

                if ((attribute as System.Data.Linq.Mapping.ColumnAttribute).IsPrimaryKey == true)
                    return pI;
            }
        }
    }
    return null;
}
```

I can see in my Entity Model that for the instance of T I am using there is a primary key set.

Can anyone advise?

Comment: EF6 sorry - I've Updated tags

Answer (score 1):

You can get that info from EF metadata (not very intuitive). For instance, the following will return the PK property names, then you can simply use reflection or `Expression.Property` to generate the necessary accessors / expressions:

```
static IEnumerable<string> GetPrimaryKeyNames<TEntity>(DbContext dbContext)
    where TEntity : class
{
    var entityType = ((System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.IObjectContextAdapter)dbContext).ObjectContext
        .CreateObjectSet<TEntity>().EntitySet.ElementType;
    return entityType.KeyProperties.Select(p => p.Name);
}
```

Comment: Problem is I don't have access to the context in this method, I just have an `IQueryable<TEntity>`.

Comment: Then you need somehow to pass that info to the method. Or use the (bit hackish) method from my answer to [Extract strongly-typed data context instance from arbitrary query](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39771701/extract-strongly-typed-data-context-instance-from-arbitrary-query).

Comment: Do you know how I can pass in the parameter to the method, e.g. something like `() => myEntity.EntityId` so I can use it?

Comment: How do you specify the order property for the method? Probably`Expression<Func<T, ...>>` or string? I guess whatever you used for sort property, you can use the same for this purpose.

Comment: I'm doing `collection.OrderByDescending(Expression.Lambda<Func<T, bool>>(sortSelectorParameter))` at the moment (for sorts provided by strings)  however if I could pass in `c => c.CustomerId` so it's strongly typed that would be preferable... I guess I just pass in a `Func<T, bool>` then? Not sure what the bool is though.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using reflection you could extend your domain model and add an interface for all your entities which will then help you with your generic code, e.g.:

```
public interface IEntity
{
    int Id { get; set; }
}
```

Then you can write some generic method like:

```
public void Update<T>(IQueryable<T> query, Expression<Func<T, object>> orderBy = null)
    where T : IEntity
{
    if (orderBy == null)
        query = query.OrderBy(m => m.Id);
    else
        query = query.OrderBy(orderBy);
}
```

This solution depends on how your entities look like, what kind of different keys they have and if you can unify them to one or more interfaces.